# Check if url hash exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, uri, uri.js

I want to check if there is a hash in the url :

This should return true:

> domain.com/balbla#hash

This should return false:

> domain.com/balbla

So I use [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html) to grab the hash

```
var uriFragment = new URI(window.location.href).fragment();
if (uriFragment.length) {
    console.log('yep')
} else {
    console.log('nope')
}
```

But that never returns **`nope`** even if there is no hash in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using directly [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash)

```
if(location.hash.length > 0) {
    console.log('yep')
}else {
   console.log('nop')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give the list of hash tags in array format.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
    return result = hash.split('#').reduce(function (result, item) {
        var parts = item.split('=');
        result[parts[0]] = parts[1];
        return result;
    }, {});
```